# AKMIDIListener not receiving SysEx

Tags: swift, midi, coremidi, audiokit, sysex

I am using AudioKit's AKMIDIListener protocol on a class to listen for MIDI messages. This is working fine for standard messages such as `Note On`, but `SysEx` messages are not coming through.

```
func receivedMIDINoteOn(noteNumber: MIDINoteNumber, velocity: MIDIVelocity, channel: MIDIChannel) {
    NSLog("Note On \(noteNumber), \(velocity), \(channel)") // works perfectly
}
func receivedMIDISystemCommand(_ data: [MIDIByte]) {
    NSLog("SysEx \(data)") // never triggers

    // More code to handle the messages...
}
```

The SysEx messages are sent from external hardware or test software. I have used MIDI monitoring apps to make sure the messages are being sent correctly, yet in my app they are not triggering `receivedMIDISystemCommand`.

Are there any additional steps required to receive SysEx messages that I'm missing?

Thanks in advance for any clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Thanks for bringing this to our attention. The SysEx receiving issue has now been fixed in the develop branch of AudioKit: https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/pull/1017

--

Instead of

```
NSLog("SysEx \(data)")
```

Have you tried?

```
if let sysExCommand = AKMIDISystemCommand(rawValue: data[0]) {
   print("MIDI System Command: \(sysExCommand)")
}
```

AKMIDISystemCommand will convert your SysEx data to something a bit more usable and is defined as follows:

```
public enum AKMIDISystemCommand: MIDIByte {
    /// Trivial Case of None
    case none = 0
    /// System Exclusive
    case sysex = 240
    /// Song Position
    case songPosition = 242
    /// Song Selection
    case songSelect = 243
    /// Request Tune
    case tuneRequest = 246
    /// End System Exclusive
    case sysexEnd = 247
    /// Clock
    case clock = 248
    /// Start
    case start = 250
    /// Continue
    case `continue` = 251
    /// Stop
    case stop = 252
    /// Active Sensing
    case activeSensing = 254
    /// System Reset
    case sysReset = 255
}
```

-- matthew @ audiokit

Comment: I have written the code necessary to check for first byte being 0xF0 and handling all other bytes appropriately. Interestingly enough, the `NSLog("SysEx \(data)")` mentioned does not trigger at all. Nothing is being logged, suggesting the `receivedMIDISystemCommand` is never run.

Thanks for the suggestion though, using `AKMIDISystemCommand` will definitely clean up my code a bit.

Comment: @Oscar - Thank you for bringing this to our attention. We are working on a fix.

Comment: @oscar We just fixed this in this pull request, so its fixed on the develop branch and will be in the next release:  https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/pull/1017